# Printing DEBUG messages in Log file

Tags: java, debugging, logging, log4j

I'm using **log4j** to manage my logs in my **Java** application. 
I can print **INFO , WARN and ERROR messages** in the log file, but I can't see the DEBUG messages. How can I also print those messages?

This is my lo4j.properties file:

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n
```

What is wrong/missing in it?

Answer (score 1):

remove this line:

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR
```